# What do screenreaders do when JavaScript cancels a hyperlink `click` event?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, accessibility, carousel

Given the code below, for a user navigating with a screen reader, will the `myHyperlink.onclick` JavaScript still execute when they follow that hyperlink, and cancel the event? My goal is for users navigating with a screen reader to navigate directly to `http://www.google.com` since they won't really see the image anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title>Accessibility?</title>
     <script>
     window.onload = function() {
         var myHyperlink = document.getElementById("slider-nav");
         myHyperlink.onclick = function() {
             document.getElementById("about-google").style.display = "block";
             return false;
         };
     };
     </script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="main">
         <a href="http://www.google.com" id="slider-nav">Google</a>
         <div id="about-google" style="display:none;">
             <a href="http://www.google.com">
                 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="Google logo" />
             </a>
         </div>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[Code also available from JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DXUqr/)

For context, I'm trying to make a carousel/slider widget more screen-reader friendly.

Comment: Screen readers sit on top of the browser, so that code will execute upon activation of the link whether a screen reader is running or not. Vision impaired users "see" the image via the alternative text supplied. I'm not clear what the purpose of hiding the image is. Perhaps you could expand a bit.

Comment: It's a carousel/slider - like the [nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/). And is an "activation" really the same as a click? Do you have a citation?

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference in browser behavior whether the link is activated by a sighted user with a mouse, a sighted user using a keyboard, or a screenreader using the keyboard. In all cases, your `onclick` handler is called, the logo is shown, and the navigation is cancelled. For keyboard users (whether sighted or not), keyboard focus will remain on the initial text link. Sighted users will see the new image appear, screenreader users won't hear anything and may be left wondering why apparently nothing happened.

You can try this yourself: [download the free NVDA screenreader](http://www.nvda-project.org/wiki/Download) (make a donation if you find it useful), and try it against the page running in IE or Firefox (Chrome support for accessibility is lagging slightly, but is catching up.) For JSFiddle pages, it's often easier to work with the result in a stand-alone page rather than as a pane, and you can do this by pulling out the frame URL and pasting it into a new browser page - http://fiddle.jshell.net/DXUqr/show/ in your case. NVDA isn't the only screenreader out there, but it's as good as any to use for checking basic web accessibility.

(Generally speaking, it's not possible to determine whether a user is using a screenreader in the first place. Your best bet is to write good accessible HTML that works for all users.)